# RaspberryPi Timer Interrupt with WiringPi

Tags: raspbian, real-time, interrupts

What I'd like to do is to create an interrupt one a timer expires after 1 ms ... 100 ms. It doesn't even have to be very accurate.

Working with microcontrollers I'm used to start a timer say in main() and get an interrupt when it expires.

But how do I set this up with the Raspberry Pi? I'm using WiringPi but so far I haven't found how to do this.

I'd be happy to get some insights on this.
Thank you very much.

Comment: The Raspberry Pi is a Linux box.  Just like any other Linux box as far as Linux timing is concerned.  Have you checked a Linux site?

Comment: Among others I've tried this:
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-an-Alarm.html
But for some reason I didn't get it to run.

Answer (score 1):

The wiringPi library provides a number of blocking timer calls.  One is used for micro second granularity (delayMicroseconds) and the other is used for milli second granularity (delay).  See:

http://wiringpi.com/reference/timing/

Using either of these, you can block your C program for a configurable amount of time.  For example, if you need to send a pulse every 50 milli seconds, you could code:

```
while(1)
{
   // Code to send a pulse
   delay(50);
}
```